# Java Jersey Declarative Hyperlinks Configuration

Tags: java, dependencies, jersey

I am confused by the Jersey Documentation Chapter 6
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/linking.html

The configuration section (6.5) doesn't say where to add the dependency etc. What file(s) need to be edited?

I am confused what I need to do all together in order to use the @Ref attribute in my code.

EDIT/UPDATE

How do I use Jersey Hyperlinking without Maven. I've grabbed the jar file jersey-server-linking-1.9-SNAPSHOT.jar but I don't know what it depends on. Can some one give me a list of jars I need to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

The dependency appears to be a maven dependency, So you'd put it in the typical maven configuration files, I'm not all that familiar with maven. This is really to make sure the Jersey linking module libraries are included in your application.

The rest of the code samples in that section refer to modifications you need to make to web.xml.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with Maven either.

Answer (score 2):

From [the Jersey Hyperlinking POM](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server-linking/1.9-SNAPSHOT/jersey-server-linking-1.9-SNAPSHOT.pom),

here's the list of dependencies you need at runtime:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```